# Как организовать двунаправленную пакетно-ориентированную передачу через UNIX-сокеты?

Tags: linux, c, unix-socket

Пытаюсь сделать сервер на датаграмном unix-сокете.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define SERVSOCKNAME "/dev/shm/mysocket"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int len;
    unsigned char buf[20];
    int unsockfd= socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(unsockfd<0) {
        perror("Create socket");
        return 1;
    }

    {
        struct {
               sa_family_t sun_family;
               char   sun_path[sizeof SERVSOCKNAME];  /* pathname */
        } addr= {AF_UNIX, SERVSOCKNAME};
        unlink(SERVSOCKNAME);
        if(bind(unsockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof addr)) {
            perror("Bind socket");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    struct sockaddr src_addr[2];
    socklen_t addrlen= sizeof src_addr;
    len=recvfrom(unsockfd, buf, sizeof buf, 0, src_addr, &addrlen);
    if(len<0) {
        perror("recvfrom socket");
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "%d %d '%.*s'\n", sizeof src_addr, addrlen, len, buf);
    len= sendto(unsockfd, "Respose", 8, 0, src_addr, addrlen);
    if(len<0) {
        perror("sendto socket");
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "sent %d\n",len);
}
```

И клиент к нему:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define SERVSOCKNAME "/dev/shm/mysocket"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int len;
    unsigned char buf[20];
    int unsockfd= socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(unsockfd<0) {
        perror("Create socket");
        return 1;
    }

    struct {
           sa_family_t sun_family;
           char   sun_path[sizeof SERVSOCKNAME];  /* pathname */
    } srv_addr= {AF_UNIX, SERVSOCKNAME};

    len= sendto(unsockfd, "Request", 8, 0, (const struct sockaddr *)&srv_addr, sizeof srv_addr);
    if(len<0) {
        perror("sendto socket");
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "sent %d\n",len);

    len=read(unsockfd, buf, sizeof buf);
    if(len<0) {
        perror("read socket");
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "%d '%.*s'\n", len, len, buf);
}
```

После запроса клиента сервер выдаёт ошибку:

```
32 0 'Request'
sendto socket: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

Это и понятно, так как длина адреса равна нулю, то непонятно куда слать ответ. Вопрос как правильно организовать приёмо-передачу?

[Похожий вопрос на англоязычной версии](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7325468/1566316)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Проблема решается биндингом клиента**.
Чтобы получать пакеты (не поток), клиент тоже должен иметь адрес. Биндинг unix-сокета в linux возможен или с пространством имён в файловой системе или с использованием абстрактных адресов. Последнее делается автоматически, если указать длину адреса равную `sizeof(sa_family_t)`, при этом выделяется уникальный адрес, длиной 6 байт (не считая `sun_family`) первый из которых нулевой, и файл сокета не создаётся:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define SERVSOCKNAME "/dev/shm/mysocket"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int len;
    unsigned char buf[20];
    int unsockfd= socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(unsockfd<0) {
        perror("Create socket");
        return 1;
    }

    struct {
           sa_family_t sun_family;
           char   sun_path[sizeof SERVSOCKNAME];  /* pathname */
    } srv_addr= {AF_UNIX, SERVSOCKNAME};

    if(bind(unsockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&srv_addr, sizeof(sa_family_t))) {
        perror("Bind socket");
        return 1;
    }

    len= sendto(unsockfd, "Request", 8, 0, (const struct sockaddr *)&srv_addr, sizeof srv_addr);
    if(len<0) {
        perror("sendto socket");
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "sent %d\n",len);

    len=read(unsockfd, buf, sizeof buf);
    if(len<0) {
        perror("read socket");
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "%d '%.*s'\n", len, len, buf);
}
```